# Re-drawing html canvas back-and-forth

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to get the canvas to change colors back and forth when clicked on, but it only changes from red to green but not back again, i've tried a while loop but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<canvas onclick="colorchangefunction()" id="testCanvas" width="320" height="240" 
style="border: 1px solid black;">
</canvas>
<script>
function colorchangefunction(){
window.alert("colorchangefunction started")
        if (color = "r"){
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.fillRect(20,20,150,75)
            var color = "g"
        }
        else if (color = "g") {
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.fillRect(20,20,150,75)
            var color = "r"
        }
window.alert("colorchangefunction ended")
}

var canvas =document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(20,20,150,75)
var color = "r"



</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not creating new variables inside the if statements should solve that for you. Instead of `var color =` just do `color =`.